# How to restore pre-Xcode 9 Find In Workspace functionality

Tags: xcode, xcode9

Before Xcode 9, the shortcut <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> would open the Find Navigator *in it's previous state*. I'm a big fan of the Regex search, so this would mean that if I had set find style to "Regular Expression", after entering the shortcut above I would be immediately able to type in a Regex.

Since switching to Xcode 9, I've found that <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> **always** switches to a "Text" based Find.

Is there a way to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I can think of is to type <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> to switch to the Find panel and then, because now the editor has become unfocused, <kbd>TAB</kbd> focuses the Search field.

This doesn't update the Search style, however it's not really a solution...